# Is there an entorage $N\subseteq \{(x, y): d(x, y)<\delta\}$ in an uniformity of locally compact metric space $(X, d)$?

Tags: uniform-spaces

It is known that if $\mathcal{U}$ be a uniformity on $X$, then every entourage $N\in\mathcal{U}$ is an open set of diagonal $\Delta_X$, but the converse of it, is not  true.

For instance,   Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with usual metric $d$. For every $\epsilon>0$, let
$$U^d_\epsilon:=\left\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :  d(x, y)<\epsilon\right\}$$
Then the collection
$$  \mathcal{U}_d=\left\{E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 : U_\epsilon^d\subseteq E, \text{  for some  } \epsilon>0\right\}$$
is a uniformity on $\mathbb{R}$.

In this example, every element of $\mathcal{U}_d$ is a neighborhood of $\Delta_\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but $\left\{(x, y) : |x-y|<\frac{1}{1+|y|}\right\}$ is a neighborhood of $\Delta_\mathbb{R}$ but not a member of $\mathcal{U}_d$.

In my research, $(X, d)$ is a locally compact, $N=\{(x, y): d(x, y)<\delta \}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is an uniformity of $X$. Can I say that there is $D\in\mathcal{U}$ with $D\subseteq N$?

Answer (score 1):

No, an entourage need not be an **open** neighbourhood of $\Delta_X$, but it *is* a neighbourhood of $\Delta_X$. E.g. $\{(x,y): d(x,y) \le \varepsilon\}$ is not open in $X \times X$ in general but it is a neighbourhood of the diagonal as it contains  $\{(x,y): d(x,y) < \varepsilon\}$ as a subset, which happens to be open. But an (even open) neighbourhood of $\Delta_X$ need not be an entourage, as your example indeed shows.

As to your final question: the answer is no, I think. Use another equivalent metric on $\mathbb{R}$ and its induced uniformity, to see this: if this property were true it would hold for $\mathbb{R}$ (locally compact) and then it would imply that all metrics on the reals would be uniformly equivalent, which they're not.

Comment: Thanks. Can we say that if metric space $(X, d)$ and uniform space $(X, \mathcal{U})$ induce the same topology, then $(X, \mathcal{U})$ is metrizable?

Comment: @user479859 No. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ in the fine uniformity, which is not metrisable.

Comment: I need to use your idea. In my research, I have a collection $\mathcal{A}= \{E[x]: x\in X\}$ for some an entourage $E\in\mathcal{U}$ and $(X, \mathcal{U})$ is compact uniform space. Can I say that $\mathcal{A}$ is an open cover of $X$. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: @user479859  No this need not be an open cover. $E[x]$ is not open, but it *is* a neighbourhood of $x$. So it is a cover by neighbourhoods so the interiors form an open cover and have a finite subcover. The corresponding $E[x]$, being larger, then also form a subcover.